# Change svn user name during commit

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

We have corporate logins like QWE098765 and using them to acess to SVN repository. I want map this names to emails, so in SVN history they will be human readable.

Currently I use post-commit hook which change svn:author revision property, but... But here is small gap between commit and change name, and sometime applications which track SVN changes (CommitMonitor, Jenkins) catch QWE098765 name instead of emails. This is not very big problem, but annoying.

May be here is other way to map names?

P.S. We use VisualSVN server for access to repository.

Comment: Somewhat similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16404616/1698557).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it with advice from Lazy Badger

Indeed, with standard tools it is not possible: 
http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2014-09/0032.shtml

But it is possible write simple script or program and operate with Subversion API directly.
I write simple implemenation of such program: https://github.com/azarkevich/SvnPreCommitAuthor

It take file path with mapping **name -> new name** and should be runned as pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it in pre-commit hook (I know about and follow "Do not modify transaction content in pre-commit", but log, author and date properties are another story and they can be changed freely)

Comment: I found that pre-commit.tmpl hook contains note, that it is safe to modify svn:author in transaction. Great.

But how to modify it? svnlook (AFAIK) readonly tool. How I can edit author in transaction? I can't find standard tool for that...

Comment: @SergeyAzarkevich - `svn help ps` (or `pe`, it doesn't matter in your case), 2-nd form: "Changes an unversioned property on a repository revision". Repo path and transaction-id you have as parameters for pre-commit hook. And don't forget to prepare *correct* `pre-revprop-change`

Comment: But svn utility does not accept transactions as argument, only revisions.

I suspect I should write small script/program for this with using Subversion API :(

Comment: I try `svn ps --revprop -r '15-g' file:///home/.../repos/`, but it failed: `E205000: Syntax error in revision argument '15-g'` Also I briefly check source codes and found that svn_opt_revision_t can be only number.

Answer (score 0):

Use a python script to change the author in a pre-commit hook:

This one is a nice example:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/log-police.py
This one modifies the log, but modifying the author works the same (simply replace *svn:log* by *svn:author*).

You'll need python-subversion. If you are on Ubuntu/Debian, then install it using:

```
sudo apt install python-subversion
```