# Automatically changing SVN Author for future commits

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Currently setting up a SVN repository that around 9 people will use. We have a problem that their current user names relate to codes (e.g. TS0343656) and this is the author name on the current SVN history logs. What I want to be able to do is edit all historical and future commits so that I can change each individuals code to their actual name automatically allowing for logs where I don't have to research the code to determine who it belongs too.

Anyone know if this is possible and if so, how?
Thanks.

Comment: Almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404616/svn-show-usernames-instead-of-user-ids

Comment: And also almost a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25687538/1698557

Comment: And for updating old commits you'll need to go through them all and `svn propset --revprop -r 1234 svn:author "New Name"` or similar, and you'll need to temporarily set up a success pre-revprop-change hook on the server to allow revprop editing. You can use `svn log --xml` to get the old names in a easier-to-parse XML format. Or you can dump the repository, edit the commit authors in the dump, and then reload the repository.